про zero runtime
Иногда вижу люди обсуждают что то и иногда всплывает понятие zero runtime, я вроде приблизительно понял что они имеют ввиду, но был бы очень признатлен если кто то подробно или объяснит или направит на нужный ресурс самому загуглить не вышло

Это когда программа не использует стандартный библиотек, и библиотек времени выполнения, т.е. например в Линукс, обращается к системе при помощи системных вызовов.
